# TryUpdateModel(model, prefix, includeProperties) returns false but some properties are still updated

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a scenario where I am editing a model in an ASP.NET MVC5 application and when I submit blank values `TryUpdateModel` returns false (correctly) but when I return the view with the same model that was passed into `TryUpdateModel` one of the properties has been updated but others havent' - even though they are all invalid.

Repro:

- Load  /Machines/Edit?serialNumber=2
- Clear Position and Name fields (manually using delete, backspace, or cut)
- Click Update button to submit form
- The `Name` property is
  updated even though `TryUpdateModel` returns false.

Is this a string only thing because I don't have a problem with the `MachinePosition` property being updated no matter what order I provide the `includedProperties` for https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.tryupdatemodel(v=vs.118).aspx#Anchor_12 in. Has anyone else come across this - it feels like I'm doing something wrong in my code because a side effect like this would surely be documented.

The only reason I noticed this was because I was returning to the main list of machines after attempting to do an invalid update and the noticed that the `Name` property was being updated for these machines yet when I debugged the code and stepped through it I wasn't hitting when the backing list was being updated/set... very confused.

My model:

```
public class Machine
{
    [Required]
    [Range(0, long.MaxValue)]
    [Display(Name = "Serial")]
    public long SerialNumber { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Range(0, 1000)]
    [Display(Name = "Position")]
    public int MachinePosition { get; set; } = 0;

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

My view:

```
@model MyWebApplication.Machine

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Update @Model.Name</h4>
        <hr />

        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <!-- Have the serial number shown in a hidden field so that it will be passed through on submit -->
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.SerialNumber)

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SerialNumber, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.SerialNumber, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.MachinePosition, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.MachinePosition, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MachinePosition, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Update" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

My controller:

```
[HttpPost, ActionName("Edit")]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult EditMachine(long? serialNumber)
{
    if (serialNumber == null)
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }

    // Get by serial
    Machine machineToUpdate = MachineRepository.Get(serialNumber.Value);
    string failureMessage = $"Model validation failed.";

    // Model state is valid at this point because we have the serial set
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        string oldName = machineToUpdate.Name;
        int oldPosition = machineToUpdate.MachinePosition;

        if (TryUpdateModel(machineToUpdate, "", new string[] { "Name", "MachinePosition" }))
        {
            Result result = MachineRepository.UpdateMachine(machineToUpdate);

            if (result.ResultCode == ResultTypeEnum.Success)
            {
                // Update the list used by the view to include the new entry
                RestoreDatabaseBackup();

                // Use PRG pattern to prevent resubmit on page refresh
                return RedirectToAction("Edit", new { serialNumber = serialNumber.Value, machineName = $"{oldName}/{machineToUpdate.Name}" });
            }

            failureMessage = $"There was an error updating the machine: {result.ResultMessage}";
        }
    }

    // Set failure message
    ViewBag.UpdateResultMessage = failureMessage;
    ViewBag.UpdateSucceeded = false;

    // When I get to here the "Name" field has been overwritten with a blank value
    return View(machineToUpdate);
}
```

Comment: Why are you using `TryUpdateModel` instead of just binding to your model using `public ActionResult EditMachine(Machine model)`? And its pointless to be calling `if (ModelState.IsValid)` with your current implementation because `ModelState` will always be valid

Comment: And what do you mean by _Backspace Position and Name fields_? Do you mean your clearing the textbox so that you post null values?

Comment: @StephenMuecke I am using `TryUpdateModel` because my understanding is that it will gracefully handle any failures by returning false rather than throwing an exception like `UpdateModel` would.

I currently do not have a controller method with the `EditMachine(Machine model` signature, I am following a Microsoft guide and they pass in the primary key field to their edit signature, do a fetch then use `TryUpdateModel` which helps prevent overposting. 

I also believe using `TryUpdateModel` also checks  the validation attributes on the  model whereas I'm not sure that your suggestion would?

Comment: @StephenMuecke yes I am clearing the textboxes so that I POST null values, I have updated the repro steps to include this.

Comment: Of course it does. I have no idea what 'tutorial' your looking at, but the standard/correct approach is to make your method `public ActionResult EditMachine(Machine model)`

Comment: And yes, it will return a `null` value for `Name` because that is what you submitted, and therefore a value of `null` has been added to `ModelState` for that property (which is then used by the `HtmlHelper` methods to set the value in the textbox)

Comment: The tutorial is here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/implementing-basic-crud-functionality-with-the-entity-framework-in-asp-net-mvc-application#update-the-edit-httppost-method. I am relatively new to ASP.NET MVC but I assumed Microsoft docs would show best practice.

I'm not sure what you mean with your last comment, my signature is already `public ActionResult EditMachine(long? serialNumber)` but earlier you were suggesting to change it to `public ActionResult EditMachine(Machine model)`?

Comment: And to prevent 'overposting' (which does not even apply in your case since your submitting values for all properties of the model), you use a view model

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161665/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-matt-stannett).